# Pass global variables through php form?

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

How do i save variable with codeigniter through pages on a form, on the first page i receive all the variables that i need on the form, i want to save those variable to postData, an be able to access them on everypage in my form?

Comment: You could try adding them as hidden form fields, and they'll be passed along in the $_POST.

Comment: can i do so in the view, or in the header

Comment: You can do so in the view, but using sessions would probably be better suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, the simplest approach would be to leverage Sessions.  For example, to assign your "global" var using sessions in php:

`session_start();`
`$_SESSION["var_name"] = $temp_var;`

Please note: `session_start();` must be included on each page when referencing any session variables.

** Note: If you do go the route of hidden form input fields, all users will be able to view the value of the variable.  In addition, you must assign the hidden input fields through out each step of the various pages that deal with the user form.

Answer (score 0):

Note that experienced users can edit hidden fields, ensure to validate data and be carefull with CSRF

You should use Session or Flashdata http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

Note: Flash variables are prefaced with "flash_" so avoid this prefix in your own session names.